# Log topic name from @kafkaListener

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Hi I am new `Spring Boot @kafkaListener`, I have below code in kafka consumer class -

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "#{'${app.kafka.consumer.topic}'.split(',')}",
        containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory",
        groupId = "${app.kafka.consumer.group-id}")
 public void receivedMessage(@Payload List<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> records,
                            Acknowledgment acknowledgment) {


   try{
       for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records){
            process(record.value(),record.topic(), acknowledgment);
       }
       acknowledge(acknowledgment);
    }catch(Exception ex){
      log.error("ERROR ", ex);
    }
}
```

In the above code I am consuming message from two different `topics`, I want to `log topic` name in `catch` block if any `error` occurred.
I tried `@Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String topic` but I am getting error for that. How can I know `topic` name from which `exception` occurred.

Answer (score 1):

You already have logic to extract the topic from the record (`record.topic()`).

You need to put your try/catch inside the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

You've already used [`ConsumerRecord#topic`](https://kafka.apache.org/25/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/ConsumerRecord.html#topic--)

You need to extract that outside the try to use in the catch e.g.

```java
   String topic;
   try {
       for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records){
            topic = record.topic();
            process(record.value(), topic, acknowledgment);
       }
       acknowledge(acknowledgment);
    } catch(Exception ex){
      log.error("ERROR on {}", topic, ex);
    }
```

Depending on how you want to process the data, you may want to put the try-catch inside the loop